# post method to remote url not working in php

Tags: php, http-post

I am trying to send a post request to a url, but it's saying this is not a post request. Please Help, here is my code.

```
<?php 

$url = "myurl";
$api = '{"Project-Key" : "string","MailFrom" : "email","From" : "email","To" : "email","Subject" : "Mail Subject","HtmlBody" : "<html><body> <img src="cid:naz.jpg"> </body> </html>"}';

$data = array(
        "authtoken" => "token",
        "scope" => "mail",
        "mailDetails" => $api
);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url,false, $context);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($result);
exit(0);

?>
```

Comment: Take a look at PHPs cURL functions, you should use them for sending POST requests. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use cURL:

```
$curlConfig = [
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data
];

curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```